# Eloquent with nested whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Currently I have this **whereHas** in a collection of my model:

```
$query = self::whereHas('club', function($q) use ($search)
{
    $q->whereHas('owner', function($q) use ($search)
    {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%');
    });

});
```

I was under the impression the code above could be as such:

```
$query = self::whereHas('club.owner', function($q) use ($search)
{
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%');    
});
```

I'm aware this is already a lot of power, but even then, if I have a nested relationship 5 levels deep, things will get ugly.

**Update:**

As stated in the comments, I ended up not making my question clear, I apologize.

I will try to use a simple example, consider `$owner->club->membership->product->package`, now from owners I want to search a certain package, it would be something like this:

```
$query = self::whereHas('club', function($q) use ($search)
{
    $q->whereHas('membership', function($q) use ($search)
    {
        $q->whereHas('product', function($q) use ($search)
        {
            $q->whereHas('package', function($q) use ($search)
            {
                $q->where('alias', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%');
            });//package
        });//product
    });//membership
});//club
```

Is this correct? Is there a shortcut?

Comment: What is the issue and what you expect?

Comment: So your question is why can't I use "club.owner" as the field?

Comment: Because every next level of nesting runs another query with WHERE id IN () clause for the nested relation. You want to search all related models with LIKE clause?

Comment: I've updated the question. @deczo Is it possible to do what you say? Here I'm just trying to search in a single related model. But what if I wanted to do as you say?

Comment: this will result in many subqueries with EXIST(), bad idea.

Comment: Just read the accepted answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Update: the PR has been just merged to 4.2, so now it's possible to use *dot nested* notation in `has` methods ( `->has('relation1.relation2)` `->whereHas('relation1.relation2, ..`  )**

Your question remains a bit unclear or you misunderstand *whereHas()* method as it is used to filter models (users in this case) and get only those that have related models fitting search conditions.

It seems that you want to find **Packages** from the context of a given **User**, so no need to use whereHas method.

Anyway depending on the relations (1-1,1-m,m-m) this can be easy or pretty hard and not very efficient. As I stated, loading nested relations means that for every level of nesting comes another db query, so in this case you end up with 5 queries.

Regardless of the relations you can invert this chain like this, as it will be easier:

---

**edit: This is not going to work atm as whereHas() doesn't process dot nested relations!**

```
// given $user and $search:
$packages = Package::where('alias','like',"%$search%")
  ->whereHas('product.membership.club.user', function ($q) use ($user) {
    $q->whereId($user->id);
  })->get();
```

---

As you can see this is much more readable, still runs 5 queries.
Also this way you get $packages, which is a single Collection of the models you wanted.

While from the context of a user you would get something like this (depending on the relations again):

```
$user
 |-club
 |  |-membership
 |  |  |-product
 |  |  |  |-packages
 |  |  |-anotherProduct
 |  |  |  |-packages
 |  |  |-yetAnotherProduct
 |  |     |-packages
 |  |-anotherMembership
  .....
```

You get the point, don't you?

You could fetch the packages from the Collection, but it would be cumbersome. It's easier the other way around.

**So the answer to your question** would be simply joining the tables:

```
// Let's assume the relations are the easiest to handle: 1-many
$packages = Package::where('alias','like',"%$search%")
  ->join('products','packages.product_id','=','products.id')
  ->join('memberships','products.membership_id','=','memberships.id')
  ->join('clubs','memberships.club_id','=','clubs.id')
  ->where('clubs.user_id','=',$user->id)
  ->get(['packages.*']); // dont select anything but packages table
```

Of course you can wrap it in a nice method so you don't have to write this everytime you perform such search.
Performance of this query will be definitely much better than separate 5 queries shown above. Obviously this way you load only packages, without other related models.

Comment: This is very nice Mr. deczo, I learned a lot from your answer. Your first sentence is very accurate.

Comment: I don't get it.. is it supported for `whereHas()` or not? Because from what I experience it is not..

Comment: It's been supported for a week now - since my latest PR was merged. However it's available currently only on `@dev` branch, for there hasn't been new release since then yet.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk what is the "proper" way to actually incorporate this code into my project? Do I need to change something in `composer.json` to ensure it downloads the version of the framework that includes this code?

Comment: You can use `4.2.*@dev` option

Comment: As a reference, I had needed a similar solution back in L4.1, and I had used nested `whereHas()` methods for this. Sth. like: `Model::whereHas('releation', function($q1){ $q1->whereHas('subRelation', function($q2){ $q2->where('...'); }); });` It worked, however as you can see it looks quite ugly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JarekTkaczyk I tried the dot nested notation with laravel 5.2 and I cant believe how easy these otherwise complicated joins where. Splendid!

Answer (score 2):

Just building upon [Jarek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23158198/1319004) one may add a scope utility to their model:

```php
public function scopeWhereRelatedIs($query, $relation, $related) {
    $query->whereHas(
        $relation,
        function ($query) use ($related) {
            $query->where('id', '=', $related->id);
        }
    );
}
```

With this in place, the usage becomes really elegant, such as:

```php
$packages = Package::where('alias','like',"%$search%")
  ->whereRelatedIs('product.membership.club.user', $user)
  ->get();
```