# Laravel Query Structure

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and am trying to create a complex eloquent query, however I cannot for the life of me work out how to do it! This is using a multivendor shop structure.

I have the following Models:

> Users has many Products
>   Products has many OrderItem
>   OrderItems belongs To Order
>   Order belongs To Users

A user can have their own products, and a user can also have their own orders. Each order has multiple Order Items, each Order Item has one product associated with it.

When I want to get it by passing back a single order object I can do the following:

```
Order::with('OrderItems', 'OrderItems.Product', 'OrderItems.Product.User')
     ->whereUser_id($this->user_id)->first();
```

This provides me all of the information I need, but how can I do it if I want the exact same info in the reverse order, eg something like...

```
User::with('Products', 'Products.OrderItem', 'Products.OrderItem.Order')
    ->where('Order.order_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

Can someone point me in the direction of the right way to do this? I've tried with `DB::Raw`, but obviously that returns a flat response rather than objects. Is that the best way to achieve this currently?

Comment: And the second query does not work? By the way `Order::with('OrderItems.Product.User')` is enough

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve. Now you're not specific about the 1st query, not mentioning the 2nd. Obviously the latter can't work, because there's no `join`, so you can't reference `orders` table when querying `users`.

Comment: lukasgeiter - No the second query does not work, it just an indication of what I'm trying to get to

Comment: Jarek Tkaczyk - I have done, I'm trying to get the same information that comes out of the first query, but reversed. So I should get a array of user objects which have product, order items and order objects nested, but are only included if they are associated with a particular order. So I wouldnt want any other products that the user sells to show up. Does that make a bit more sense? Thanks

Comment: lukasgeiter - also thanks for the note on Order::with('OrderItems.Product.User'), I'd seen someone else write it out fully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you want but you can use a combination of `with()` (with a closure) and `whereHas()`:

```
User::with(['Products.OrderItem.Order' => function($q){
    $q->where('Order.order_id', 1);
}])
->whereHas('Products.OrderItem.Order', function($q){
    $q->where('Order.order_id', 1);
})
->get();
```

`with()` will eager load only the orders with id 1 and `whereHas` will filter out all users that don't have an order with id 1.

Comment: Ahh I understand, so its a two step process. Get all of the data using with, and then filter it using whereHas.
For me the with method works, but whereHas only works when I remove everything except the first relationship.
`$users = User::with(array('Products.OrderItems.Order' => function($q){
   $q->where('orders.id', 4);
  }))
  ->whereHas('Products', function($q){
   $q->where('Products.id', 92);
  })
  ->get();`

Its throwing `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Products.OrderItems.Order()`
Thank you for your help so far, its helped my understanding alot!

Comment: Update your Laravel installation (`composer update`). Support for nested relations with `whereHas` has recently been added.

Comment: Ahh thanks lukasgeiter, I can see from the comment [on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153678/eloquent-with-nested-wherehas) from @Jarek that its still in dev which is why I dont have it at the moment
Thanks both for your help!