# Mysql join three table/ Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables Beneficiary, Questions, Responses..Beneficiary

```
Benficiary
id name
1  user1
2 user2
3 user3

Questions
id question             type
1  what is your hobby   hobby
2  address              contact
3  phone                contact
..questions upto 500 and i need to select according to its type

Response
id beneficiary_id question_id response
1  1              1           football
2  1              3           5354353
3  2              1           basketball
4  3              2           cityname
5  3              3           432423
```

Beneficiary table and Question table are static but response table joins both of them. I tried to do this from laravel query but it gives me only responses 
sql query

```
select response,questions.question, beneficiarys.name 
from responses RIGHT join (questions,beneficiarys) 
on beneficiarys.id = responses.beneficiary_id && questions.id = responses.question_id 
where questions.sheet_type = 'SCDS' OR questions.sheet_type = 'SMM'
```

laravel query

```
$beneficiaries =       Beneficiary::with('quests','response')->whereHas('response', function ($query)use($sheet_type) {
             $query->where('beneficiary_id', '>', 0);
        })
->whereHas('quests',function($query)use($sheet_type){
                $query->where('questions.sheet_type','=',$sheet_type);
                $query->orWhere('questions.sheet_type','=','SCDS');
            })
        ->where('updated_at','>=',!empty($this->request->from_date)?$this->request->from_date:$from)->where('updated_at','<=',!empty($this->request->to_date)?$this->request->to_date:$date)->get();
```

Beneficiary Model

```
public function response()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Response');
}

public function quests(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Question',   'responses','beneficiary_id','question_id');
```

}

Question Model

```
public function response(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Response');
}

public function bens(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Bebeficiary', 'responses','question_id','beneficiary_id');
}
```

Response Model

```
public function beneficiary(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Beneficiary', 'beneficiary_id');
}

public function question(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Question', 'question_id');
}
```

I need all the question according to its type(type is selected by user from view) and i need output like this

```
beneficary  hobby     address phono  ....
user1       football  null    4244   ....
user2       basketball null   null   ....
```

is there any way to achieve it with sql or laravel query*

Comment: Can you post relationships between Eloquent models?

Comment: One solution is to join tables using `querybuilder`..Other option is to use the relationship concept...

Comment: If you need it in querybuilder i can post it in answer..

Comment: @jitheshjose if its possible using querybuilder then please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

this is the mysql select, maybe is a better way to it but this work

```
SELECT b.name,hobby.response as hobby,address.response as addres,phone.response as 
phone FROM beneficiary as b
left join (select *  from response where question_id=1 ) as hobby
      on hobby.beneficiary_id = b.id
left join (select *  from response where question_id=2 ) as address
      on address.beneficiary_id = b.id
left join (select *  from response where question_id=3 ) as phone
      on phone.beneficiary_id = b.id
```

Comment: thank you..i have like 400 of question can i also get questions dynamically? and beneficiaries who have reponded

Comment: well in mysql you can make pivot tables but i dont really sure if you can make it dinamically so if i where you i will create this in laravel only calling one field and make a forearch for every field in question, then use a union. i think that could funtion

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $res = DB::table('responses')
   ->join('questions','responses.question_id','=','questions.id')
   ->join('beneficiarys','responses.beneficiary_id','=','beneficiarys.id')
   ->select('responses.*','questions.question','beneficiarys.name')
   ->where('questions.sheet_type', '=','SCDS')
   ->orWhere('questions.sheet_type','=','SMM')
   ->get();
```

Use the result as

```
 foreach($res as $res)
 {
   echo $res->name;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Will get result from this query. Laravel Support customization as well.

```
$sSQL = "SELECT * FROM RESPONSE 
INNER JOIN QUESTION ON QUESTION.id=RESPONSE.QUESTION_id
INNER JOIN  BENEFICIARY ON BENEFICIARY.id=RESPONSE.BENEFICIARY_id";
DB::query($sSQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it Eloquent way you could try using **whereHas** on your nested relationships. Try something like :

`Beneficiary::with('response.question')->whereHas('response.question')`

For more references try this link [Eloquent with nested relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153678/eloquent-with-nested-wherehas)