# Laravel whereHas Filter sub relation

Tags: laravel

Is that any method to filter the employees and the manpower table record does not return also?

```
$result = Pwra::with('purchaseOrder', 'manpower')
->where('pwra_dt', $date)
->where('time_session', $session)
->whereHas('manpower.employees', function ($q) {
    $q->where('status', 1);
})
->get();
```

Pwra Class

```
public function manpower()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Manpower', 'pwra_uuid', 'pwra_uuid');
}
```

Manpower Class

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Employees', 'employees_uuid', 'employees_uuid')->where('status', 1);
}
```

What I expected is: When the employees Status = 0, it will not return any record even manpower.

Comment: is this you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153678/eloquent-with-nested-wherehas

Comment: I have been tried but still does not work for me

Comment: i think you need to do 2 time `whereHas` or `join`

Comment: Um... any example for 2 times `whereHas` ?

Comment: it does not work `with('manpower.employees')`

Comment: `with()` method is for **eagar loading**. So `manpower.employees` wont work. If you use `Join` method, then it may work like this way.

Comment: Maybe `whereHas` cannot handle this case. Let me try to use `join()` in the query. Great Thanks

Comment: Let me know 1 thing `->whereHas('manpower.employees'…` with this you want to query on employees table or manpowers table?

Comment: I wanna filter manpower table records when employees `status == 0 ` , it will not return manpower records. if employees `status == 1` , it will return the manpower record.

Comment: So pwra hasMany manpower & manpower hasOne employee, like this ?  **Pwra -> (hasMany) ->ManPower -> (hasOne) -> Employee**

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: If you solve the issue then give an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try 2 level `whereHas()`

```php
$result = Pwra::with('purchaseOrder', 'manpower')
    ->where('pwra_dt', $date)
    ->where('time_session', $session)
    ->whereHas('manpower', function ($q) {
        $q->whereHas('employees',function($subQ){
            $subQ->where('status', 1);
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

`whereHas('manpower.employees'` it will not work

Comment: I have been tried this query but it keeps showing the employees with status = 0

Comment: what is datatype of `status` varchar or int.?

Comment: `INT` for the `status`

Comment: If use `manpower` with `wherehas()` method. Then you dont need to do that with `with()` method,  `with('purchaseOrder', 'manpower')` will be `with('purchaseOrder')` because you call the `manpower` with `wherehas()` method