# Laravel with limiting results still brings the results

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following table relationship:

```
  Results -> 
    Objectives -> 
      Users -> 
        User
```

And my current query is the following:

```
$results = \App\Models\Results::with('objectives')
     ->with('objectives.users')
     ->with('objectives.users.user')
     ->get();
```

It works great. But now, I'd like to return only the users that are active.

```
$results = \App\Models\Results::with(['objectives' => function($query)
{
    $query->with(['users' => function ($subQuery)
    {
        $subQuery->with(['user' => function($thirdQuery)
        {
            $thirdQuery->where('active', true);
        }]);
    }]);
}]);
```

But the result of this query returns an empty user (which is the one that is no longer active).

```
{
    "id": 267068,
    "objective_id": 9291,
    "user_id": 79598,
    "created_at": "2020-11-04 00:52:32",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-04 00:52:32",
    "user": null
},
{
    "id": 267069,
    "objective_id": 9291,
    "user_id": 79599,
    "created_at": "2020-11-04 00:52:32",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-04 00:52:32",
    "user": 
    {
        "id": 79599,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "created_at": "2020-10-01 05:53:34",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-01 05:53:34",        
    }
},
```

Applying `->whereHas('objectives.users.user')` also doesn't seem to do anything!

Comment: Eloquent doesn't allow dot nested whereHas relations, one option might be to repeat the code you have with `with`. You can check this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153678/eloquent-with-nested-wherehas

Comment: @SandroVardiashvili yes it does, you can use `whereHas('something.something');`

Comment: hmm are you sure? I've had the cases when I needed nested whereHas but it never worked.

Comment: @SandroVardiashvili at least with two levels, yes, I'm sure because I use it in other queries and so far it works ok. But with three levels..first time trying.

Comment: did you pass a closure to `whereHas` to do the filtering?

Comment: is suggest to prevent  nested where has using [Laravel Join](https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join)